# What method will return ActiveRecord owner object from class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have users which have items:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now I want to add a class method to item for a customized record creation:

```
def self.create_personalized
  create description: "#{user.name}' item"
end
```

But of course, since this is a class method, `user` is undefined.  But if I call it using `user.items.create_personalized`, then there is an associated user via the relationship.  I know that `Item.create_personalized` is aware of the user because this works:

```
def self.create_personalized
  item = create
  item.update_attribute :description, "#{item.user.name}'s item"
end
```

But clearly that's not the best way to access the owner object.  What is the correct method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option I've found is `current_scope.proxy_association.owner`.  It's still a bit indirect, but it returns the exact object I'm looking for.

```
def self.create_personalized
  user = current_scope.proxy_association.owner
  create description: "#{user.name}'s item"
end
```

Comment: @Guacamolay On what object and in what Rails version?  `ActiveRecord::Base` children do not have a `#proxy_association` method in Rails 4.2.6.

Answer (score 5):

If you do

```
Item.scope_attributes
```

then you'll get a hash of any attributes from the current scope that apply to item. These are the ones that would be extracted from the scope if you called `create`. These are the DB level attributes so you'll get a user id rather than the user itself.